# CONNECTION_LOSS error in Zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

We have a consumer (using the kafka-node library) which consumes messages from a topic and then throws the following error when the offset is commited and the consumer is closed.

```
kafka-node:HighLevelConsumer HighLevelConsumer healthcheck_0d6af285-d35e-4edf-9d90-c5cdd7c37666 is attempting to rebalance +88ms
kafka-node:HighLevelConsumer HighLevelConsumer healthcheck_0d6af285-d35e-4edf-9d90-c5cdd7c37666 stopping data read during rebalance +1ms
kafka-node:HighLevelConsumer HighLevelConsumer healthcheck_0d6af285-d35e-4edf-9d90-c5cdd7c37666 assembling data for rebalance +0ms
kafka-node:zookeeper Exception: CONNECTION_LOSS[-4]
```

Has anyone seen this before and why a "connection loss" would be reported.  The ZK server was up and running all the time.

Thanks for any help anyone can offer

Comment: There are [a few related issues](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/issues?q=is%3Aissue+CONNECTION_LOSS+is%3Aclosed) in that project which are supposedly fixed, but in our case it's still not working either.